# How to add linearmodel2 summary results to a timeseries of measurements by a loop?

Tags: r, loops, plot, regression

I have a some data that contains CO2 flux measurements from two-devices through various months. I've already created the timeseries plots with this loop:

```
library(lmodel2)
layout(matrix(1:12, 4,3, byrow = TRUE))
par(mar=c(4,4,0,0)+0.5)

for (i in 1:12){
  plot(data_Hainich_2017$co2_flux_6262_R3[data_Hainich_2017$Month==i], 
       data_Hainich_2017$co2_flux_7200_HS[data_Hainich_2017$Month==i],
       xlab="CO2_flux_6262_R3", ylab = "CO2_flux_7200_HS")

  lm_co2_flux_6262_R3_7200_HS <- lmodel2(co2_flux_7200_HS[Month==i] ~ co2_flux_6262_R3[Month==i], 
                                         data=data_Hainich_2017, nperm=99)
}
```

[image: This is my plot]

I already extracting the values that I need from my model (MA)-[row][column]

```
intercept <- lm_co2_flux_6262_R3_7200_HS$regression.results[[2]][2]
slope <- lm_co2_flux_6262_R3_7200_HS$regression.results[[3]][2]
r.square <- lm_co2_flux_6262_R3_7200_HS$rsquare
```

Now I wish to add the intercept, slope, r² and abline to the timeseries but I cannot figure out how. So there should be 12 intercepts, 12 slopes and 12 R² (for each own plot). This is the ouput of my lmodel2, which gives me 3 different types of models, that's why [row][column].

```
{Regression results
  Method   Intercept    Slope Angle (degrees) P-perm (1-tailed)
1    OLS  14.9923058 1.965779        63.03736              0.01
2     MA -20.2206577 4.621907        77.79161              0.01
3    SMA  -0.1518283 3.108107        72.16498                NA}
```

I would appreciate so much your answer!

Comment: I used the lmodel2 package, which is for computing a specific type of linear model. The output of the model is 3 different regressions and I need to choose the MA (major axis regression), based on the [row] and [column] positions.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could help me. I have been stuck here for 2 hours almost.